# Better approach than hidden field to store data in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'd like to know if a better approach exists  to store data in html content.
At the moment I got some values stored in my html file using hidden field. These values are generated by code behind.

**Html:**

```
<input type="hidden" id="hid1" value="generatedValue1" />
<input type="hidden" id="hid2" value="generatedValue2" />
```

And therefore I get those values on client side using jquery, in order to pass them to an ajax request.

**JQuery**

```
$.ajax({
  data:{
     var1 : $('#hid1').val(),
     var2 : $('#hid2').val()
  }
);
```

So is this the correct way to do this, or does it exist a smoother solution to achieve the same result? Since I don't need these values to be posted on page submit the `input hidden`is probably gross.

Comment: Do you need the values to be transferred by `form`, for example to some other page?

Comment: Nope , i pointed it out , that's hy i think i am misleading.

Comment: You say you don't need the values posted, but your JQuery uses them in the `$.ajax`

Comment: You can pass the values from code-behind to a js variable in JSON format.

Comment: @James Indeed , I got a lot of actions available on that page, a standard form submit and some ajax request which allow the users  to change some datas of the page. Those values are not requested on form submit, only used with the ajax request which is a get btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need those in a form, then just make them variables in your JavaScript. To output them, encode them via the [`JavaScriptSerializer` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx):

```
<%
    // Presumably somewhere in your C# code...
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
%>
<script>
var hid1 = <%= serializer.Serialize(valueForHid1) %>;
var hid2 = <%= serializer.Serialize(valueForHid2) %>;
</script>
```

*(See note below about globals.)*

Using them later:

```
$.ajax({
  data:{
     var1 : hid1,
     var2 : hid2
  }
);
```

Globals: As shown there, `hid1` and `hid2` end up as globals (on most browsers, they do when you use hidden fields as well). I recommend not using globals, but instead wrapping everything in scoping functions:

```
(function() {
    var hid1 = <%= serializer.Serialize(valueForHid1) %>;
    var hid2 = <%= serializer.Serialize(valueForHid2) %>;

    // ....    

    $.ajax({
      data:{
         var1 : hid1,
         var2 : hid2
      }
    );
})();
```

If for some reason you *have* to use a global, use just one:

```
var myOneGlobal = {
    hid1: <%= serializer.Serialize(valueForHid1) %>,
    hid2: <%= serializer.Serialize(valueForHid2) %>
};
```

Using that later:

```
$.ajax({
  data:{
     var1 : myOneGlobal.hid1,
     var2 : myOneGlobal.hid2
   }
);
```

You can output an entire object graph to one variable (perhaps `myOneGlobal`) with the serializer:

```
<script>
var myOneGlobal = <%= serializer.Serialize(objectWithData) %>;
</script>
```

Comment: Althought you deserve a fair +1 for effor put into the answer, I think the main idea is wrong - manualy adding variables? And what if there is a lot of them? Or the number of them is dynamic? I think that JSON is the better option in here.

Comment: @KamilT: The above could certainly be made more dynamic. JSON isn't required, though, as we're dealing with JavaScript, not text data.

Comment: Since the values are generated by the server and not static , i still need some kind of storage in the html to be able to access them from client side.

Comment: I am kinda new to javascript and jquery , guess i need to read more about global. Ty.

Comment: @nubinub: No, you can use JavaScript variables for that. I've added a note showing how you might use server-side info and output it to the page as a variable via the `JavaScriptSerializer` class.

Answer (score 6):

What I usually do is adding the values as **data-** attributes to the html form:

```
<form data-field1="generatedValue1" data-field2="generatedValue2">
...
</form>
```

And then, retrieve them with jQuery:

```
... 
$form = $( my_selector_to_take_the_form );

data:{
     var1 : $('form').attr('data-field1'),
     var2 : $('form').attr('data-field1')
  }
```

With this, you won't post any hidden field

Answer (score 5):

You should use the HTML5 data attribute.

i.e `<a href="#" data-YOURKEY="YOUR-VALUE">My Link</a>`

You can easy access this attributes i.e with jQuery

```
$(".mylink").attr("data-YOURKEY");
```

John Resig explained it well:
http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Please also read the specs from HTML5-Doctor
http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

..and if you like to go a bit deeper:
http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes

Comment: I think that OP doesn't want the elements on page, that's why he is now using the hidden inputs.

Comment: Ty for the documentation, really interesting.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the new HTML5 "data" attributes. (http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

Your codebehind section would do something like this:

```
<ul data-listname="{put name here}">
    <li data-key="{put key here}>
        Item1 
    </li>
</ul>
```

And then in your jQuery you can do:

```
var firstId = $('li').first().data('id');
var list = $('ul').data('listname');
```

Make sure to only use lowercase after the `data-`
I have found, that it will not work correctly otherwise.
You can also set the data like this:

```
$('#something').data('smthgnelse', 'Hi there');
```